# not showing Namenode Datanode ResourceManager etc

Tags: hadoop

While giving Command jps :

it is showing only

```
some _pid jps
```

not showing services others likes

```
Namenode
Datanode
ResourceManager
etc
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us the logs for these services... And the commands you're using to start them. Start with just fixing the Namenode, though

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the service. If services is not started it will not show anything. To start the service use start-all.sh, than check jps